# Redis giving error even after redis connected in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

I have redis installed on my system and its running as well.
[image: redis installed and running]

from node application, im using below code to work with redis.

redis.js

```
    const redis = require("redis");

let client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {});

let isRedis = false;

client.on("connect", function () {
    console.log(`connected to redis`);
    isRedis = true;
});


client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("redis connection error " + err);
    throw err;
});

client.on("end", function (err) {
    console.log("redis connection end " + err);
});

module.exports = {
    SetRedis,
    GetKeys,
    GetRedis,
    GetKeyRedis,
    delRedis
};
```

im using node index.js command to run the application which should also give me "connected to redis" when the connection is established, but i'm not getting this message on my console .

the npm package is also present in package.json

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working redis.js,

```
    const redis = require("redis");
let isRedis = false;

(async () => {
let client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {});// create config
client.on("connect", function () {
    console.log(`connected to redis`);
    isRedis = true;
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("redis connection error " + err);
    throw err;
});

client.on("end", function (err) {
    console.log("redis connection end " + err);
});

function GetKeyRedis(key) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("dd----",key,isRedis);
        if (isRedis) {
            client.get(key).then((data,err) => {
                if(err){
                   reject(err);
                 }
                if(data){
                    resolve(data)
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    GetKeyRedis
};

await client.connect();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Node Redis 4.x doesn't allow you to pass in discrete arguments for the host and port. The canonical example of connecting to Redis with Node Redis is this:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

(async () => {
  const client = createClient();

  client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

  await client.connect();

  await client.set('key', 'value');
  const value = await client.get('key');
})();
```

If you want to connect to somewhere other than localhost on port 6379, I recommend using a URL. Like this:

```js
createClient({ url: 'redis://awesome.redis.server:6380' });
```

But if you want finer control, you can find all the gritty [configuration options](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md) in the documentation on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are making mistake while making connection.
It should have been

```
let client = redis.createClient('127.0.0.1', 6379, {});
```

rather than

```
let client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {});
```

Comment: that too not working.

Comment: have you added client.connect(); ?
As I can't see in your code snippet.

Comment: can you please let me know where to add in redis.js. may be you can make changes in redis.js which i mentioned above.